# Is there a way to pre-populate the location area in the nautilus "open file" or "save as" dialogs?

Tags: nautilus, dialog

I wonder if it is possible have Nautilus Gnome/Unity configured to always pre-populate the location area in the "open file" or "save as" dialogs .

I want to pre-populate it with the current directory.
Copying the current directory to the clipboard
See attached screen shots.

**Current state: (on 14.04):**
[image: not prepopulated]

**What I want to achieve:**
[image]

Nautilus Main Window *does* prepopulate the location field with the path:
[image]

I know there exists a possible workaround with the nautilus-open-terminal extension, but that is not what I'm asking here.